# Virtual methods and subclasses in c++

Tags: c++

So i'm trying to better understand virtual methods.
I have a base class **Sensor** and several subclasses **SensorTemp** **SensorPh** **SensorOrp**

```
class Sensor
{
public:
virtual void updateValue();
}
```

the subclasses then override updateValue with their own method definitions (this happens in each of the subclasses)

.h file

```
#include "Sensor.h"
class SensorTemp : public Sensor
{
 private:


 public:

};
```

.Cpp file

```
#include "Sensor.h"
#include "SensorTemp.h"
void Sensor::updateValue(){
    int reading = analogRead(pinId); 
    float voltage = reading * 5.0;
    voltage /= 1024.0;
    currentVal = voltage * 100 ;
    Serial.print("temp: "); Serial.println(currentVal);
}
```

My issue is this works for the first subclass declaration, although the following will have a compiler error: updateValue() .... first defined here ld.exe : : Disabling relaxation: it will not work with multiple definitions

So I'm stuck on what type of approach I should take if I want to define the method differently from each subclass?

Any insight would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You subclass implementation should look like:

```
void SensorTemp::updateValue() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to learn dynamic dispatch through `virtual` keyword. In dynamic dispatch the actual type of object determines the appropriate method from that class to be called. To achieve this, the base class should provide a `virtual` method and each of the sub-classes should overrie that virtual method to provide their own behavior.

So each of your subclass should **override** the virtual method.

**//.h file**

```
class SensorTemp : public Sensor
{
 private:


 public:
    virtual void updateValue();

};
```

**//.cpp file**

```
void SensorTemp::updateValue() 
{
// ....
}
```

If your sub-classes do not override the `virtual` method then irrespective of the actual *type* of the object(be it base or sub-class) the Base class `virtual` method will be called.

Comment: Awesome, I misunderstood how the override worked, thank you for your detailed clarification!